# Any LINQ alternative for loop in reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, typedescriptor

I have a type T with fields+properties that i'd like to populate from a dictionary, pref case insensitive

I can obviously do

```
foreach(PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties() )
.....
```

and then

```
foreach(FieldInfo pi in t.GetFields() )
.....
```

Hoping there's a better way, perhaps using LINQ ?

Comment: Where did the dictionary come from?  Consider skipping the dictionary entirely and using Serialization.

Comment: I believe the task is to transform a dictionary into an instance of type `T` filling its members from the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option,

```
var propDict = t.GetProperties().ToLookup<PropertyInfo, string, Action<object, object>>(
    p => p.Name, p => (obj, val) => p.SetValue(obj, val, null));

var fieldDict = t.GetFields().ToLookup<FieldInfo, string, Action<object, object>>(
    f => f.Name, f => (obj, val) => f.SetValue(obj, val));

var memberDict = pDict.Concat(fDict).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

...and then to use something like...

```
Dictionary<string, object> outDict;
foreach (var keyval in outDict)
    memberDict[keyval.Key](container, keyval.Value);
```

...though not sure if it makes too much sense as going through properties/fields is relatively simple anyway, an idea maybe.

Comment: An interesting way of avoiding a helper class to wrap different APIs of `PropertyInfo` and `FieldInfo`. A bit monstrous though. :)

Comment: I didn't say it isn't 'monstrous' :) just killing time while it compiles. The OP wanted LINQ, so there it is

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything better. `PropertyInfo` and `FieldInfo` types have different APIs for setting values, therefore you won't be able to fill their values in a uniform way even if you gather them into an `IEnumerable<MemberInfo>`.

Well, you could write a wrapper that would handle both `PropertyInfo` and `FieldInfo` in a uniform way encapsulating the different APIs. But 2 `foreach` loops are easier anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what are you planning to do with `pi`.

- If transform to some new class then you can

  ```
  t.GetProperties().Select(pi =>
  t.GetFields().Select(pi =>
  ```
- If read properties and output them, then `foreach` loop is better than LINQ.